# Containers on GCE. How to deal with large containers?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

After installing [SpaCy](http://spacy.io/) high accuracy model to my python pipeline, the docker container size went from 60mb to 3.5GB. Consequently a Container Optimized Compute Instance boot up time increased significantly as well. Is there any way I could push the SpaCy part to GCR ones and then only deal with the 60mb container?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY requirements.txt server.py en_core_web_trf-3.1.0.tar.gz .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-pubsub==2.8.0
./en_core_web_trf-3.1.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start your GCE, the machine starts and then download your huge container. (Download and extract it). It can take several seconds to achieve that, maybe few minutes.

One solution is to create a custom image with COS image + your container already downloaded. Then, deploy this custom image on your VM. Now, when it start, the container is already here, and you just have to run it.

However, you need to rebuild a custom image each time that you create a new container. And you break the main advantage of the container (to be independent of the machine image)